# Hacer Delay al llamado de una función personalizada en Jquery

Tags: jquery, funciones, function

tengo una función a la cual le envío dos variables que al llamarla necesito hacer un `Delay`.
El código de cuando la llamo es:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){         
        $('#FormAplicaCan').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $.ajax({
                url:'../phpAux/ProcesoAplicaCan.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:$(FormAplicaCan).serialize(),
                beforeSend: function () {
                $("#RespuestaAplicacion").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>Aplicando , espere por favor.');
                },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (resp) {   
                    if (resp.Registro < 1){
                        //alert( "No pudo Cargarlo" );
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").html(resp.Mensaje);
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").addClass('alert alert-warning');
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").show();
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").delay(8000).hide(600);
                    } else {                    
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").html(resp.Mensaje);
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").addClass("alert alert-success");
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").show();
                        $("#RespuestaAplicacion").delay(8000).hide(600);
                        $('#myModalAplicaCan').delay(8000).modal('toggle');
 setTimeout(listarS(resp.listando,resp.aPuesto)),8000;                                        
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

La funcion se ejecuta directamente sin esperar los 8 segundos...

Tambien utilicé:

```
listarS(resp.listando,resp.aPuesto).delay(8000);
```

Tampoco funciono
Cómo debo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví, paso el código por si alguno le sucede lo mismo:

En vez de

```
setTimeout(listarS(resp.listando,resp.aPuesto)),8000;
```

va el siguiente codigo:

```
setTimeout(listarS,8000,resp.listando,resp.aPuesto);
```

O sea que si tenes una función con variables el codidigo general para `setTimeout` es:

```
setTimeoput(NombreDeTuFuncion, tiempo en milisegundos, variable1, variable2...variableN);
```

Answer (score 0):

En javascript no existe delay.
Lo más parecido es setTimeout que ejecuta cierta acción luego de x tiempo.
Si necesitas esperar a que se ejecute cierto código para hacer otra acción investiga un poco acerca de async await y then.

Comment: Existe delay, pero en este caso no se como usarlo...

Comment: En jquery existe delay()